# Filling up a NxM matrix such that A[i,j]=A[i-1,j] NAND A[i,j-1]

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, matrix, dynamic-programming

**inputs:**

i) A string of length N, composed of 1s and 0s

ii) A string of length M, composed of 1s and 0s

iii)A list of space separated integer pairs i,j

**Output:**

A[i,j] for every i,j given as input.

A[i,j]=A[i-1,j] NAND A[i,j-1].

The first row is given as the first string and the first column is given as the second string (element at top right corner is empty).

I have solved through the brute force approach of iterating through every element in the matrix., and I am trying to think of ways to optimize my code. I want to make it run fast enough so that it runs under 2-3 seconds for N=10^5 and M=10^5.

```
r=[]
N=list(map(int,list(input())))
M=list(map(int,list(input())))
n=len(N)
m=len(M)
Y=[1 for j in range(m+1)]
A=[Y.copy() for i in range(n+1)]
A[0]=[-1]+M
for i in zip(A[1:],N):
    i[0][0]=i[1]
for k in range(1,min(n,m)+1):
    for i in range(k,n+1):
        if (A[i-1][k] and A[i][k-1]):
            A[i][k]=0

    for j in range(k+1,m+1):
        if (A[k-1][j] and A[k][j-1]):
            A[k][j]=0

q=int(input())
for i in range(q):
    qj,qi=map(int,input().split())
    r.append(str(A[qi][qj]))
```

Comment: @jww: I think you must have posted the wrong canned comment on this question, or posted your canned comment on the wrong question, or something, because this question clearly is *not* asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource.

Comment: @ruakh - No, that was the right one. Eshonai dumped his/her requirements with no code or effort. That's a signal (to me) he/she wants someone to give the code and explain it. Hence a tutorial.

Comment: Alright, I added some code as well.

Comment: @jww: Ah. In that case, you've misunderstood the passage you quote; it's talking about questions that are *explicitly* asking for an off-site resource. If the question is asking an on-site answer, but you think any answer would have to be too long and tutorial-like for an on-site answer, then that's "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking at the patterns produced by some example sequences, e.g.:

```
    X XXXX   X X XX X X XXXXXXXX
XXXX X X XXXX X X XX X X X X X X
 X XX X X X XX X X XX X X X X X 
X X XX X X X XX X X XX X X X X X
XX X XX X X X XX X X XX X X X X 
X X X XX X X X XX X X XX X X X X
XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX X X X 
 XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX X X X
X XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX X X 
 X XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX X X
X X XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX X 
 X X XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX X
 XX X XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX 
 X X X XX X X XX X X X XX X X XX
 XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX X X X
X XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX X X 
 X XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX X X
 XX XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX X 
 X X XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX X
 XX X XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX 
 X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X X XX
 XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X X X X
X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X X X 
XX XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X X X
X X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X X 
 X X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X X
X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X 
 X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX X
X X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX 
XX X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X XX
 XX X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X X
X XX X X X XX X X XX X X XX X X
```

I haven't analysed it closely, but at first sight it seems that once you have simulated the first couple of rows and columns, then the rest of the pattern is just a diagonal extension.

Comment: You're right, it does follow that pattern! Thanks for bringing this to my attention.